# iOS Getting NULL Image after converting bytes to image

Tags: image, xamarin.ios, gzip, compression

I am trying to first convert an Image to bytes and zip it using GZipStream in Xamarin iOS. Here is the code

```
var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var zipFileName = Path.Combine(documentsPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss")+".zip");

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(zipFileName, FileMode.Create))
using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
{
    gz.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);``
}
```

It Zips the file. when i decompress it to verify the image, it is returning NULL. Here is the code

```
string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var zipFileN = Path.Combine(documentsPath, zipFile);
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(zipFileN);
byte[] decompressed = Decompress(file);
UIImage newImg = GetImagefromByteArray(decompressed);

public static UIImage GetImagefromByteArray(byte[] imageBuffer)
    {
        try
        {
            NSData data = NSData.FromArray(imageBuffer);
            UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);  
            return image;  // image  GETTING NULL
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

newImg is getting NULL. The original image is in the PNG format. When i compare bytes for original image and decompress image they are same.

Comment: Is `data` coming out NULL too, or just `image`?

Comment: Only image is NULL. data has value

Comment: what have you done to debug this?  Are you your decompressed data stream is identical to your original data stream (ie, is still a valid image).

Comment: According to bytes the decompressed data bytes are same as original image data bytes.